# update `headerRight` inside a screen that is hosted by stack navigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation

I have created a stack navigator:

```
import {createStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack';

const TheStack = createStackNavigator();
```

Then, I have a `LandingScreen` under this navigator:

```
<TheStack.Navigator ...>
  <TheStack.Screen
        name="LandingScreen"
        component={LandingScreen}
        options={{
          title: '',
          headerLeft: null,
          headerRight: () => (
            <MyHeaderRightComponent />
          ),
        }}
      />

<TheStack.Navigator>
```

As you can see above in `options` of the screen, there is `headerRight`, I have declared using `MyHeaderRightComponent` as `headerRight` so that it is shown on the right side of the header on screen.

Here is my `LandingScreen.js` :

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {View, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';

const LandingScreen = ({navigation}) => {
   // How can I access the `headerRight` here to update the `headerRight` to another component? 
   ...
}
```

My question is how can I access the `headerRight` inside my *LandingScreen.js* so that I can update the `headerRight` to show a different component on my header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently had a similar problem, whereby I had to alter the header title from within a screen. This can be done with `navigation.setOptions()`.

#### Example

This should be in your `LandingScreen` component.

```js
navigation.setOptions({headerRight:() => <NewHeaderRightComponent/>})
```

Comment: No problem, let me know how it goes.